# Dynamically read the classes in a project folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a VS project and I need to dynamically read the class names in a project folder so I can instantiate them. I can read the file names but then I would have to parse the contents because the class name inside the file may not match the file name. Is there an easier way?

[image]

Comment: Try `nrefactory`

Comment: You can use Reflection to get a list of all classes in your assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of going through source code files, just list iterate through all the classes in your assembly using reflection. You can then instantiate each class if you wish.

```
string mynamespace = "FantasticBeasts";

var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == mynamespace
        select t;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes

To instantiate each class, you can then use:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance